# Functional Testing in Symfony

Tags: symfony

I am new in testing.I want to test my function.I have successfully installed phpUnit. I check many tutorials on internet.But I could not get the proper information regarding testing. Here is the my function code:

```
public function loginAction(Request $request)
    {
    $session = $this->getRequest()->getSession();
    if( $session->get('userId') && $session->get('userId') != '' && $session->get('type') == '2')
    {
            //if user is login then it will be redirect to login page               
       return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('registrarGeneral_dashboard'));
    }
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();
    $repository = $em->getRepository('DRPAdminBundle:User');
    if ($request->getMethod() == 'POST')
        {
        $session->clear();
            $userName = $request->get('username');
            $password = md5($request->get('password'));

        //find email, password type and status of User
                $user = $repository->findOneBy(array('username' => $userName, 'password' => $password,'type'=>2,'status'=>1 ));
        $userEmail = $repository->findOneBy(array('email' => $userName, 'password' => $password,'type'=>2,'status'=>1 ));
            if ($user) 
            {

            //set session of User login                        
                $session->set('userId', $user->getId());
            $session->set('type', 2);
            $session->set('nameRegistrar', $user->getFirstName());
            $session->set('pictureRegistrar', $user->getPicture()); 

            //echo "<pre>";print_r($session->get('picture'));die;            
                return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('registrarGeneral_dashboard'));
            } 

        if ($userEmail) 
            {

            $session->set('type', 2);                      
                $session->set('userId', $userEmail->getId());
            $session->set('nameRegistrar', $userEmail->getFirstName());
            $session->set('pictureRegistrar', $userEmail->getPicture()); 

            //echo "<pre>";print_r($session->get('picture'));die;            
               return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('registrarGeneral_dashboard'));
            } 

            else 
            {
                    return $this->render('DRPRegistrarGeneralBundle:Pages:login.html.twig', array('name' => 'Invalid Email/Password'));
            }

    }    
        return $this->render('DRPRegistrarGeneralBundle:Pages:login.html.twig');
     }
```

how to test this function? Please help

Comment: http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/testing.html

Comment: firstly ask yourself what you want to test. Do you want test output? This code would be pretty hard to unit test you should really refactor it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what you want to test but here is an exemple of what you can do to test user fonctionnalities :

```
public function testUserPageDown()
{
    $client = static::createClient();

    $client->request('GET', '/user/login');
    $this->assertTrue($client->getResponse()->isSuccessful());

    $client->request('GET', '/user/register');
    $this->assertTrue($client->getResponse()->isSuccessful());
}

public function testUserFirewall()
{
    $client = static::createClient();

    //Trying go to user routes without being logged
    $client->request('GET', '/user/profile');
    $this->assertTrue($client->getResponse()->isRedirect());

    $client->request('GET', '/user/profile/edit');
    $this->assertTrue($client->getResponse()->isRedirect());

    $client->request('GET', '/user/profile/editpassword');
    $this->assertTrue($client->getResponse()->isRedirect());
}

public function testUserFormRegister()
{
    $client = static::createClient();
    $crawler = $client->request('GET', '/user/register');

    $buttonCrawlerNode = $crawler->selectButton('submit_user_register');
    $form = $buttonCrawlerNode->form();

    $testForm = array(
        'wineot_databundle_user[username]'  => 'test',
        'wineot_databundle_user[firstname]'  => 'test',
        'wineot_databundle_user[lastname]'  => 'test',
        'wineot_databundle_user[mail]'  => 'test@mail.fr',
        'wineot_databundle_user[plain_password][first]'  => 'blabla321',
        'wineot_databundle_user[plain_password][second]' => 'blabla321'
    );

    $response = $client->getResponse();

    $client->submit($form, $testForm);
    //If the submit is true that mean that the register is ok
    $this->assertTrue($response->isSuccessful());
}
```

I hope that will help you do undestand how to test.